# How to convert .dbf file to .csv file using custom activity ? Any complete answer will be very helpful for me as i am new to this

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

How to convert .dbf file to .csv file using custom activity ? Any complete answer will be very helpful for me.

I tried to rename the file and view the data but the data we got is unstructured format. I want to load the data in my ssms tables.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried? and any errors you are facing with?

Comment: i used the copy data activity to rename the file and and storing in storage account. but the data we we are getting is unstructured format

Comment: Could you share what you have tried with custom activity?

Comment: in custom activity what python code we need to give and how to use custom activity ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `.dbf` file to `.csv` file you can try with the below code. It uses sample `marks.dbf` file and it converts to `.csv` file as shown in the below output.

```py
def dbfToCsv(dbfFile, csvFile):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(dbfFile):
            print("Error: The specified .dbf file does not exist.")
            return
        
        newTable = DBF(dbfFile)
        
        with open(csvFile, 'w', newline='') as newcsvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(newcsvfile)
            
            writer.writerow(newTable.field_names)
            
            for record in newTable:
                writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
        
        print("Conversion completed successfully.")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

dbfFilePath = r"C:\Users\****\****\marks.dbf"
csvFilePath = r"C:\Users\****\****\Desktop\MyTrails\output2.csv"

dbfToCsv(dbfFilePath, csvFilePath)
```

Below is the sample `.dbf` file:
[image]

After running the above code it successfully converts `.dbf` to `.csv` as shown in the below output.

**Output:**

```js
Conversion completed successfully.
```

```js
REG_NO,NAME,MARKS
1000,Aaradhya,86
1001,Adah,91
1002,Adhira,72
1003,Alisha,69
1004,Amoli,88
```

use this code in `.py` file and execute this in custom activity. You can go-through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) to know more about the custom activity.